# Nested foreach for subitems in C#

Tags: c#, foreach, nested

I want to add the data from the database as an item and sub-item to a dictionary. When I have a dictionary sorted by items and sub-items, I will be able to add this dictionary to the combo-box as I wish. I have a database structure like this:

```
id      item            slug            parent_id
--------------------------------------------------
1       Audi            audi            0
2       BMW             bmw             0
3       Ferrari         ferrari         0
4       A3              a3              1
5       A4              a4              1
6       A5              a5              1
7       A6              a6              1
8       Mercedes-Benz   mercedes-benz   0
9       CLA             cla             8
10      CLS             cls             8
11      C Series        c-series        8
12      S Series        s-series        8
13      SLS AMG         sls-amg         8
14      Mitsubishi      mitsubishi      0
15      Porsche         porsche         0
16      Skoda           skoda           0
17      Tesla           tesla           0
18      A7              a7              1
19      Q3              q3              1
20      SL              sl              8
21      300             300             8
22      Toyota          toyota          0
23      Volkswagen      volkswagen      0
24      A8              a8              1
25      Q2              q2              1
26      Volvo           volvo           0
27      Q5              q5              1
28      Q7              q7              1
29      RS              rs              1
30      80 Series       80-series       1
```

In this database structure, I want to get datas to a dictionary that sub items will be located under their parent item with teqel. This is the simple schema:

```
Audi
    - 80 Series
    - A3
    - A4
    - A5
    - A6
    - A7
    - A8
    - Q2
    - Q3
    - Q5
    - Q7
    - RS
BMW
Ferrari
Mercedes-Benz
    - 300
    - CLA
    - CLS
    - C Series
    - S Series
    - SL
    - SLS AMG
Mitsubishi
Porsche
Skoda
Tesla
Toyota
Volkswagen
Volvo
```

To accomplish this, I coded like this:

```
var listed_items = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 0, "--- Select item ---" } };
foreach (var it in _db.Items.Where(x => x.parent_id == 0))
{
    listed_items.Add(Convert.ToInt32(it.id), it.item);

    foreach (var sub_it in _db.Items.Where(x => x.parent_id > 0))
    {
        if (it.id == sub_id.parent_id)
        {
            listed_items.Add(Convert.ToInt32(sub_id.id), "   - " + sub_it.item);
        }
    }
}
```

But sub-items are not located under the parent items.

Comment: @Amy, What signs did you use to show the database structure and list structure in this way? When I couldn't do what you did, I used comment quotes. I knew it looked badly.

Comment: Multi-line code is formatted with triple backticks (or by indenting with four spaces).  Single backticks are used for inline-code, such as `this is some inline code`.  You should be able to see the complete edit history to see how I did it (triple backticks).  I made the edit to make your question look a little nicer, is all.

Comment: use order by parent's id in inner query and replace `Where(x => x.parent_id > 0)` to `Where(x => x.parent_id == it.id)` you may also remove  no longer needed `if (it.id == sub_id.parent_id)`

Comment: @Selvin, parent ids and item ids may not always be compatible as in this example. At that time order by might not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to group them by the parent ID, then

```
var dictionary = _db.Items
                    .GroupBy(x => x.parent_id)
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
```

will put all items into a `Dictionary<int, List<dbItemTypeName>>` where the key is the parentID, and the list contains all items with that parentID.

If you're wanting to add all items to a combobox at once, a Dictionary is not your best bet, as it does not guarantee it will maintain order. You'd want to use a SortedDictionary.

```
var dictionary = _db.Items
                    .OrderBy(x => x.parent_id == 0 ? x.id : x.parent_id)
                    .ThenBy(x => x.parent_id)
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.id, y => y);
var sortedDictionary = new SortedDictionary<int,DBItemType>(dictionary);
```

where `DBItemType` is the type of the items contained in `_db`. If you're wondering what's happening here - we are first ordering by the result of `x.parent_id == 0 ? x.id : x.parent_id` because it will group the parent items with the children (we use the regular `id` if the `parent_id` is 0), then ordering by `parent_id` to get the parent item to the top (it's `parent_id` is 0).

If you're wanting to select string representations of the items, instead of the items themselves:

```
var dictionary = _db.Items
                    .OrderBy(x => x.parent_id == 0 ? x.id : x.parent_id)
                    .ThenBy(x => x.parent_id)
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.id, y => y.parent_id == 0 ? y.item : $"   -{y.item}");
var sortedDictionary = new SortedDictionary<int,string>(dictionary);
```

Then be sure to set the `DisplayMember` property of the `ComboBox` to `"Value"` and the `ValueMember` property to `"Key"`

Comment: Thank you, but, this shows only 3 item. But, all items must be listed. I add a screenshot. [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/vnc2K0V.jpg)

Comment: See the bottom section of my answer